# End of The Matrix Revolutions

Tags: ending, the-matrix-revolutions

In the third part of the *Matrix* trilogy, what was happening to Neo?
Why does he get connected to the machines (all that piercing in head and spine), when he was blind. Did Neo know what he was doing? Explain the ending, or I'll say conclude the trilogy.

Comment: My interpretation of that scene was that Neo and the machines knew that Agent Smith would absorb Neo.  The machines connected to Neo so that later they would have a direct connection to Agent Smith through which they could kill him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo was killing two birds with one stone by going to the Machine City. First, he needed to parley with Deus Ex Machina for peace. Secondly, he knew that by being directly connected to the mainframe, he could ensure that Smith would be destroyed no matter what. As it happened, Smith proved to be unbeatable, so Neo allowed Smith to absorb him, which directly connected Smith to the mainframe, allowing Deus Ex Machina to delete the Smith virus.

If Neo had simply been beaten to a pulp and killed, Deus Ex Machina would have ordered the sentries to finish off Zion. However, as Neo ensured that Smith was given access to by Deus Ex Machina, their agreement was fulfilled.

Comment: was Smith causing any harm to Deus?

Comment: Deux Ex Machina was losing control of the Matrix, as the Agents were getting absorbed by Smith, but the machines hadn't yet been hijacked in the real world. However, they knew that the virus would eventually affect them if it wasn't destroyed.

Comment: its also worth noting that a "Smith" did eventually make it out into the "real world". knowing that that is a possibility, they would eventually try to overthrow both man and machine. the enemy of my enemy is my friend, considering how deus and neo "co-operated"